# How aspherical can a Gömböc be? 

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, convex-geometry

A [Gömböc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6mb%C3%B6c) is a homogeneous massive convex solid that can rest on a horizontal plane in just two positions of equilibrium under gravity: one stable and the other unstable. How small a proportion of the volume bounded by its circumscribing sphere can a Gömböc occupy?

Comment: @John Bentin: please take a look at the edit that I made to see how to insert hyperlinks using the MarkDown syntax. 

Comment: By the way, a similar (but slightly different) question was posed and answered in Varkonyi and Domokos' _Intelligencer_ article on the mono-monostatic bodies. Take a look at page 4 of http://www.gomboc.eu/100.pdf

Comment: It's too trivial a point to start an editing war over, but *gomboc* is too good a word to leave out of the English language. Thus it should have English orthography: no capital or umlauts, please!

Comment: @John Bentin: I disagree.  Gömböc is a perfectly good english word in that orthography --- english is very flexible.

Comment: @Theo Johnson-Freyd: Are you arguing for both the capital and the umlauts, or just the umlauts?

Comment: @John Bentin: Don't worry, if the word comes into common usage, the eventual disappearance of the diacritics is virtually assured, whether you campaign for it or not.  Most words in the Wikipedia list are commonly seen without diacritics.  http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_words_with_diacritics  The capitalization is likely to disappear too, unless people perceive it as a trademark name.

Comment: @Timothy Chow: Yes. Perhaps everyone will be happy if we reserve the capitalized umlaut-laden version of the word for the branded product while using the easily typed *gomboc* for the mathematical definition.

Comment: Update of the broken link in the 2nd comment: http://www.gomboc.eu/docs/100.pdf.